# Why is collider.enable = true not working in my code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

Working on an asteroid like game, when my ship gets hit it blows up and I Instantiate a new ship and surround it with a shield for a few seconds. While the ship is surrounded by the shield I disable collisions for a few seconds. This all works. After a few seconds I hide shield (SetActive(false)) and then set playerCollider.enabled = true.  The shield hides but the collider will not re-enable.

code for when killed

```cs
 public void KilledWaitTime()
    {
        SetLivesText();
        Instantiate(player); //respawns player after killed
        shield.SetActive(true);
        playerCollider.enabled = false; //disables collider while shield up.
        Debug.Log("collider = " + playerCollider.name);
        Debug.Log("player = " + player.name);
        Invoke("RemoveShields", 3);
    }
```

code for removing shield and re-enabling collider

```cs
 public void RemoveShields()
    {
        shield.SetActive(false);
       // Collider pc = player.GetComponent<Collider>();
        Debug.Log("collider pc = " + playerCollider.name);
        Debug.Log("player pc = " + player.name);
        playerCollider.enabled = true;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Instantiate(player);`, you are creating a completely separate object from the previous player object. When you instantiate the player object, you need to re-assign `playerCollider` to refer to the collider on the newly created object.

You also may want to keep your player prefab and your current player objects separate:

```
private GameObject playerPrefab;
private GameObject player;

public void KilledWaitTime()
{
    SetLivesText();
    player = Instantiate(playerPrefab); //respawns player after killed
    playerCollider = player.GetComponent<Collider>();

    shield.SetActive(true);
    playerCollider.enabled = false; //disables collider while shield up.
    Debug.Log("collider = " + playerCollider.name);
    Debug.Log("player = " + player.name);
    Invoke("RemoveShields", 3);
}
```

Comment: You could additionally make the type of `playerPrefab` and `player` directly `Collider` then you don't have to call `GetComponent` since [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) will always return the type of the given prefab ;)